# Synthesist summoner and Linnorm Death Curse, Taiga rage power

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon, rage

I am playing a Synthesist summoner level 7. I am thinking of taking 6 levels in skald to get the Linnorm Death Curse, Taiga rage power but i am not sure if it would activate while using raging song when my eidolon dies.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. While you've already a couple of answers to this question (one of them mine!), it might also be useful to explain *why* you're entertaining this idea for your character.  Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 2):

The [skald](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/) [rage power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Rage-Powers-Ex-) [**taiga linnorm death curse**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/linnorm-death-curse-taiga-su/) says, "The [affected] character’s melee attacks deal an additional 1 point of electricity damage. If the [affected] character is knocked unconscious or killed by an attack or spell, the attacker suffers the curse of electricity." The rage power then goes on to describe the curse of electricity: a failed Will saving throw means the attacker gains electricity [vulnerability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Vulnerabilities-Ex-or-Su-).

While a [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist/) [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/)'s fused eidolon *cannot* be knocked unconscious, it *can* be killed: "The synthesist gains the eidolon’s hit points as temporary hit points [and w]hen these hit points reach 0, the eidolon is killed and sent back to its home plane." So if a skald's supernatural ability raging song is used for the supernatural ability inspired rage to grant the fused eidolon the rage power taiga linnorm death curse and the synthesist summoner's eidolon is subsequently killed, the rage power should function normally.

---

#### An Aside: This is *extremely* suboptimal

Unless *either* the party is similarly unoptimized *or* the summoner is vastly overshadowing the remainder of the party *or* everyone else in the party is throwing around huge amounts of electricity damage, there's very little reason to make this sort of investment. The rage power taiga linnorm death curse base effect (the extra electricity damage) is trivial (especially at the proposed level 13!), and the curse itself only has the *possibility* of affecting one enemy *if* an ally is removed from the encounter!

A typical summoner will be much better served by taking six more levels of summoner than by taking six levels of skald solely to acquire and share this rage power with his eidolon.

Comment: If the summoner (or someone else in the party) summons minions wouldn't they gain the rage power, too when raging song is active? That could be a use if it works like that.  but it would still be suboptimal.

Comment: @Umbranus O, sure, that's *a* use, but, yeah, it's still a pretty bad use, what with the curse having a save DC of 10 + ½ the creature's HD +the creature's Cha modifier (summon a high-Charisma monster  for *this?*) *and* the noncumulative nature of electricity vulnerability. Even in weird and contrived scenarios, I am not seeing how this alone justifies lighting on fire 6 levels of a previously fine PC's career.

Comment: @HeyICanChan the eidolon cannot be target of this because he cannot be affected by the Skald's rage song.

Comment: @ShadowKras But when *both* of them are affected and one of them dies, a creature affected has still died, right? *And* the effect isn't specifically targeted? (I hadn't dug into the synthesist's exceptions like you have, so I'm  happy to be wrong.)

Comment: *Your* character is affected by inspired song, not the eidolon.

Comment: @ShadowKras But *your character* can't be affected separately. That is, the *single unit* was affected, but *when the eidolon dies*, it may die alone but it dies having been affected simultaneously with the synthesist.

Comment: Exactly, you are both a single creature, and whenever the eidolon disapears, any effect that was affecting the merged-form will now affect the character.

Comment: Relevant faq: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9oba

Comment: This is probably the single archetype with the most faq entries and questions on paizo's forum...

Comment: @ShadowKras (*I know!* I *hate* synthesist questions! We're reaching the comment limit, and I've no time to chat. Sorry!) The skald's death curse is not targeted, and part of an affected creature *still* died. I think we're to the point of table variation on the topic, but if you want to pull apart the FAQ entry to prove your point, I can be persuaded: I'm not married to this stance and find it a little wobbly anyway. (Except that 6 levels in a class to get to where this is even a thing is *terrible* and should be looked upon generously by the GM!)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, if your Eidolon is killed while under the effect of a Linnorm Death Curse rage power, the curse will be applied to whoever killed the Eidolon. The specific interaction of wording:

> If the character is knocked unconscious or killed by an attack or spell, the attacker suffers the curse of electricity (Will negates).

and

> The synthesist gains the eidolon’s hit points as temporary hit points. When these hit points reach 0, **the eidolon is killed** and sent back to its home plane.

A better question might be - why would you ever allow your fused eidolon to be killed in this way, when you can use Fused Link to sacrifice from your own hit points and keep it alive? Presumably being fused with your Eidolon is the basis of much of your combat effectiveness and it seems unlikely that giving an enemy a chance of becoming vulnerable to electricity is worth sacrificing the benefits that the fusion gives you. Fused Link allows you to keep the Eidolon alive until you must both go down.

Answer (score 0):

### No, it wouldn't

Your eidolon cannot be targeted by any effects while you two are a single creature and anything that would affect the eidolon will affect your character instead (with exceptions, see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98883/are-the-synthesist-and-his-eidolon-different-creatures-when-an-effect-isnt-targ)).

> Neither the synthesist nor his eidolon can be targeted separately, as they are fused into one creature.

This is explained on a [FAQ item](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9oba) aswell.

So, if the eidolon cannot the targeted by your *Inspired Rage*, whenever it reaches 0 hit points and dies, there is no eletricity damage on the attacker because **the eidolon wasn't affected by the rage power**.